# C# Auto use of PC Name in Connection String

Tags: c#

Is there a possible way to use your program with any computer with out changing a connection string? By the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2008 for creating a windows form application and Microsoft SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2012 for my database.

And here are some of my codes, this is my class `konek`

```
class konek
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlConnection getConnect()
    {
         conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source='" + System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName + "'\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=it12-ProjectMedicalAssistance;Integrated Security=True");
         return conn;
    }
}
```

And this is my way of using it to my other window forms for me to access the database

```
conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
conn.Open();
```

Comment: Just use `.\SQLEXPRESS`. The `.` (dot) is already equivalent to your local machine name

Comment: @haim770 ok sir let me try

Comment: @haim770 Thanks a lot sir, A single dot can change my life, Thank you Sir Thank You!

Comment: The host name `localhost` always points to the local machine. So does `.` or `(local)`. It's in the docs. The documentation can save a lot of lives.

Comment: This connection string should be used: [https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/attach-a-database-file-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto no, it shouldn't. This question is about connecting to a local database, not how to attach a database file.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What I focused to the connection string is usage of SQL Express instance, not the database attachment. OP can drop `AttachDBFileName` and use `Initial Catalog` for existing DB.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto what you posted is wrong no matter the edition. You can connect to Express just like any other edition. You can use databases just like any other edition. You *don't* need to attach a database file. What you linked to is **ONLY** about user instance databases. BTW the feature is deprecated, will be removed in the future and is considered [a *bad* idea in general](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/)

Answer (score 3):

Just use .\SQLEXPRESS. The . (dot) is already equivalent to your local machine name - Credits to @haim770 for the answer

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=it12ProjectMedicalAssistance;Integrated Security=True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the connection string like this

```
Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True
```

or

```
Data Source=(local)\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True
```

. and (local) and YourMachineName are all equivalent, referring to your own machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use port number in connection string in case of named SQL Server instances as below. You need to know which port is being used by your named instance. If you know the port number then even the instance name is not required. Machine name and port number combination is enough to make SQL connection:

```
Data Source = (local),5122;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True
```

**OR**

```
Data Source = myMachineName,5122;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True
```

**OR**

```
Data Source = .,5122;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True
```

On my machine the named instance was using port # 5122.